# Product and sum on Gaussian distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

Is it true that

$$ k N(0,1) + p = N(p,k) $$

where N(0,1) is the standardized gaussian distribution?
My question arises from the observation that sometimes I've found a distribution with some constants that multiplies it or sums to it.
For example, in the case of sample variance of a gaussian r.v. we can say:

$$ \frac {(n-1) s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}  $$

But I can approximate the chi squared distribution with a gaussian one when n is big (assume that it is, I've found this on ):

$$ \frac {(n-1) s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \sqrt{2n} N(0,1)+n $$

So, I can execute the following transformations of this last formula?

$$ s^2 \sim \frac {\sigma^2 \sqrt{2n}}{n-1}N(0,1) + n $$

$$ s^2 \sim N\left(n, \frac{\sigma^2 \sqrt{2n}} {n-1} \right)$$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: The answer will depend on what you mean by that $1$ in $kN(0,1)+p=N(p,k)$.

Comment: It might also depend on what you mean by multiplying the distribution by $k$ and adding $p$ to it--even assuming these are numbers and that $k$ is positive.

Comment: It seems you have created two accounts which limits your ability to edit your own question - [see here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge them.